# Error in file: "......sql/log_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.1.1.php" after upgrading from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: database, error, upgrade

I used the same software installer (Softaculous) that I actually used to install Magento in the first place. Now - Softaculous upgraded my Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 1.9.2.4. The upgrade was done successfully but now - when I try to access the home page - it tries for a very very long time and then I get the following Error on the home page:

```
Error in file: "/home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/sql/log_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.1.1.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Trace:
#0 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.1.0', '1.6.1.1')
#2 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.1.0', '1.6.1.1')
#3 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/account/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/account/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

**

```
Magento 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.4
             Apache Version 2.4.23
             MySQL Version  5.6.31
             PHP Version    5.5 (I also tried switching to 5.6.25)
```

**

I also get notifications via Email saying that:

> This message is to alert you that the username ACCOUNT has exceeded
>   their MySQL connection limit. Please view the details below.
>
> Server: new.SERVER.net User: ACCOUNT MySQL Connection Limit:  Current
>   MySQL Connections: 150

I have increased the limit many times before but I get these notifications every once in a while. I get them a lot since the upgrade I just did...

Answer (score 0):

open your database go to `core_resource` tabel and in this entry `admin_setup` change version and data version to `1.6.1.2` for both value hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Murtuza....I went in there and it already has that setting (1.6.1.2) for both the 'version' and 'data version' under 'mg_core_resource' - 'admin_setup'

Comment: Do it for `adminnotification_setup`

Comment: I did - still the same - it tries and tries to pull the page forever and I expect it will spit out the Error afterwards....